# Bind a textbox to a datagridview row

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datagridview, textbox

I want to bind DataGridView Rows all from the same Column to a textbox, to make the text of that cell appear in that textbox when I click on cells from that Column. The problem is I can't use e.RowIndex. Is there any way to do this with properties or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TextBoxes` `DataBindings` property. Something like...

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", GridDataSource, "ColumnOrPropertyName"));
```

If the grid does not have a data source, then you can wire up the grids `SelectionChanged` event and reference the grids `CurrentRow` property. Something like...

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null) {
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColumnName"].Value.ToString();
  }
}
```